# Show that the ideal is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^{\ast}-$ algebras and $A \otimes B$ denotes minimal(spatial) tensor product. Let $I$ and $J$ be closed ideals of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Is it true that

> Is it true that $I \otimes J$ is closed ideal of $A \otimes B$?

It Is clear that  $I \otimes J$ is ideal but how to prove that this ideal is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the minimal tensor product $A \otimes B$ is defined as an abstract Banach space completion of $A \odot B$. Similarly, we can form the the minimal tensor product $I \otimes J$.

There is a canonical $*$-homomorphism
$$I \otimes J \to A \otimes B.$$
Using this $*$-homomorphism, we can identify $I \otimes J$ as a subset of $A \otimes B$. The image of a $*$-homomorphism is automatically closed, so actually your question is a matter of definition: the answer to your question is yes, by the way we define $I \otimes J$ as a subset of $A \otimes B$.

Comment: Do you know any classification of primitive ideals of minimal tensor product?

Comment: @Math Lover I'm not aware of such thing.